# map in a JFrame using url

Tags: java, swing, google-maps-api-3, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I'm trying to add a google-map in my frame, I read here that the best way is opening an URL, so, I did:

```
    JTextPane myMap = new JTextPane();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    scroll.getViewport().add(myMap);


    scroll.setBounds(40,240,1200,644);
    background.add(scroll);

    try{
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/html/maps.html");

        myMap.setPage(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I see nothing, if I use helloWorld.html instead of maps.htm I see the content.

Why is it happening?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look at this thingy, seems like this is what you wanted, too good [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/) and here is one [Sample Code Snippet](http://java.dzone.com/articles/web-browser-your-java-swing) . Hope this will surely help you somewhere :-)

Answer (score 4):

better could be to read the tutorial [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), then there are two ways

```
JTextPane myMap = new JTextPane();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(myMap);
```

or

```
JTextPane myMap = new JTextPane();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
scroll.setViewportView(myMap);
```

don't `setBounds`, let's this job for proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: I put my JScrollPane into a background image, if I dont use setBounds it isn't shown. Why I shouldn't use it?

Comment: besauce your JScrollPane shouldn't be resiziable with container, e.g. JFrame, simple add myFrame.add(scroll), then you use built in BorderLayout, then you can use setSize for JFrame if you really needed to restict pixels ration on the screen

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this,  the said URL is not your `Application Resource`, so you have to access it like this, I guess

```
try
{
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/");
    tpane.setPage(url);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is a small Program for your help :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTextPaneExample
{
    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextPane Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextPane tpane = new JTextPane();
        tpane.setContentType("text/html");
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane();
        scroller.setViewportView(tpane);

        try
        {
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/");
            tpane.setPage(url);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        frame.getContentPane().add(scroller);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new JTextPaneExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, this works, but if I change your URL and I write: http://www.maps.google.es it shows a blue page, and it tries to draw google maps controlers, but they aren't good ones.

I supposse this is not the best way to add a map.

thanks!

Comment: @user1256477 : Yeah, I guess that's what I thought of since, the images aren't coming in the right way. Not so good in this URL thingy yet :(